# Are questions about raising children in Christian beliefs on topic here?

Tags: discussion, site-definition

I know there's parenting.se, but are questions specific to raising kids as Christians welcome here?

Comment: This seems very related to, if not a strict subset, of http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/165/advancing-in-christian-living-and-our-walk-with-jesus

Comment: @Flimzy This was asked specifically because there is a SE site dedicated to parenting.

Answer (score 4):

I would say yes, as long as the question has some bearing on faith.

If you want to ask about the value of teaching your kids a catechism, that would be very much on topic. As a counter example, questions about potty training would be off-topic here and should be migrated to [Parenting.SE](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What about 'How did OT parents potty train kids?' :) ... on a serious note, +1 since this is what I think too

Comment: @DTest: I think that particular question might be on topic over on [Gardening.SE](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/).